# Некорректное обновление отображение списка CardView

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, cardview

Возникла проблема при использовании CardView. При скроллинге списка, возникает наложение старых данных, т.е. список как будто отображается в бекграунде, см. ссылку на видео. Ниже выложил код, который использовал.
Подскажите, в какую сторону смотреть для решения данной проблемы.

**Видео**: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7p8pihs6aqxkovb/device-2016-07-14-151103.mp4?dl=0

**Код фрагмента, в котором все отображается:**

```
public class PreviewFragment extends Fragment {
    private List<Person> persons;
    private RecyclerView rv;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_activity, null);
        rv=(RecyclerView)v.findViewById(R.id.rv);
        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        rv.setLayoutManager(llm);
        initializeData();
        initializeAdapter();
        return v;
    }

    private void initializeData(){
        persons = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0; i<50; i++){
            persons.add(new Person("Name_" + i, "years old " + i*i, android.R.drawable.arrow_up_float));

        }
        }

    private void initializeAdapter(){
        RVAdapter adapter = new RVAdapter(persons);
        rv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

**Layout для Фрагмента**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:paddingTop="60dp">
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

**Layout элемента списка**

```
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/person_photo"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/person_name"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/person_photo"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:textSize="30sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/person_age"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/person_photo"
        android:layout_below="@+id/person_name"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: у вас возможно накладыватся друг на друга фрагменты. Как вы добавляете фрагмент в `Activity`?

Comment: В главной Activity лежит FrameLayout, который заменяю на нужный фрагмент следующим образом:                                                                                     PreviewFragment previuFragment = new PreviewFragment();
        fTrans = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fTrans.add(R.id.fragment_container, previuFragment);
        fTrans.commit();

Comment: @АлександрТкаченко для замены фрагментов используется метод `replace()` 

а `add()` непосредственно добавляет.

Comment: Asgard, большое спасибо. На самом деле это и было решением проблемы. Подскажите, почему так происходило? При первом запуске происходило добавление нового фрагмента в пустой контейнер. Почему это приводило к такому поведению?

Comment: @АлександрТкаченко, см. мой ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод `add()` как и следует из названия - помещает фрагмент в контейнер. И как только случалась ситуация, при которой этот код повторно вызывался(поворот экрана\перезапуск приложения), то он снова добавлял фрагмент в этот контейнер - но не было механизма, удаляющего старый фрагмент.

Такой механизм присутствует в `replace()`.

Поэтому если вам нужно добавить динамически фрагмент, и вы знаете, что он заменяться не будет - используйте `add()`, если же этот контейнер должен заменяться другими фрагментами - используйте `replace()`.

Comment: Это не совсем верно, при `replace` выполнится лишняя работа по созданию фрагмента, тогда как его можно восстановить из памяти без единой строчки кода. Т.е. тот фрагмент, который виден за добавленным при повороте экрана и есть восстановленный из памяти фрагмент. Так что нужно не `replace` использовать, а проверять есть ли фрагмент в памяти. См. мой ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Добавление фрагмента в активити при повороте экрана должно происходить так:

1. Проверяем есть ли фрагмент в памяти
2. Если нет - добавляем.

Если не проверять есть ли в памяти фрагмент и вместо добавления использовать `replace()`, то будет сделана лишняя работа по созданию фрагмента. Если в нём при этом ещё к-л работа по получению данных происходит, то будет и она выполнена. Не надо так. А надо так:

```
Fragment fragmentHotelsList = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container);
if (fragmentHotelsList == null) {
    fragmentHotelsList = new ModelsListFragment();
    getSupportFragmentManager().
            beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, fragmentHotelsList)
            .commit();
}
```